# Powershell summing NoteProperties

Tags: google-maps, powershell, google-maps-api-3

```
Get-Direction "google" "apple" -inMiles | select-object instructions, distance, duration
```

This gives a workable output. I want to be able to use the `Measure-Object` cmdlet in order to calculate the driving time and distance.

Since the response of `distance, duration` is not a numeric number, a string, how do I pull that information and then sum it?

`Get-Direction "google" "apple" -inMiles | select-object instructions, distance, duration | Measure-Object -Property Distance -sum`
does not work as to be expected. So I figure I will need at least a `for loop` to iterate through each istance or a `$_.`

Comment: I'd suggest querying the API directly. The `GoogleMap` module returns the textual representations from the directions, so will contain lots of rounding errors

Comment: I really hate trying to query directly. You have to break the URL into a thousand variables in powershell because of how "&" is interpreted... Utterly horrible.

Comment: Not at all, you can construct the query uri with a single `-f` operation

Comment: what does `-f` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I'd suggest querying the Directions API directly:

```
$From = 'google'
$To = 'apple'
$APIKey = 'ASDASdDGerYYeb7_zfd' # replace with actual key
$requestURI = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin={0}&destination={1}&mode=driving&units=metric&key={2}' -f $From,$To,$APIKey

$APIResponse = Invoke-WebRequest $requestURI -UseBasicParsing
$Route = $APIResponse.Content |ConvertFrom-Json |Select -First 1 -Expand routes
```

Now we can grab the exact numerical value (in meters) from the API route response:

```
$TotalDistance = $Route.legs.steps |Select Instructions,@{name='Distance';e={$_.distance.value}},Duration |Measure-Object  Distance -Sum
```

And finally convert the total distance to miles:

```
$TotalMiles = 0.000621371 * $TotalDistance.Sum
```

This way you don't have to create complex logic for whether the output is in miles/feet, and you'll get a more accurate result

---

If you insist on using `Get-Direction`, use a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to extrapolate the numerical value, for example using regex:

```
$directions = Get-Direction "google" "apple" -inMiles | select-object instructions, @{name='Distance';expression={$value,$unit = $_.distance -split ' ',2;if($unit -eq 'ft'){$value}else{5280 * $value}}}, duration
```

Inside the expression part of the `distance` calculated property, we split the value into two parts using the `-split` operator. The first part will be the numerical value ("0.2" from "0.2 mi"), and the second part the unit ("mi" from "0.2 mi").

Then, we check if the units are feet, if so just return the value. Otherwise we assume the value is in miles, and so we convert it to feet.

Now you can use `Measure-Object`:

```
$TotalDistance = $directions |Measure-Object Distance -Sum
```

Since we converted all value to feet previously, finally we convert the total distance back to miles:

```
$TotalMiles = 0.000189394 * $TotalDistance.Sum
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what the second command is doing. Also, I will be gathering it from `csv`. It is much easier to work with.

Comment: `$TotalDistance = $Route.legs.steps |Select Instructions,@{name='Distance';e={$_.distance.value}},Duration`

Comment: The hashtable argument to `Select` is called a calculated property. Basically you modify an existing property and attach it as a new property to the object

Comment: Or I could just use the Get-Distance cmdlet... I just need to get their distance api and it does it.